# How to return JSON response object

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am getting this error even though I added media formatter as follows. I am testing with **postman**. Postman headers content-type is application/json and body is x-www-form-urlencoded. How can I fix it?

> "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an
>   object of type 'Initiate' from content with media type 'text/html'.",
>   "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException"

Here is my code sample:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/pin")]
public class GameController : ApiController
{

    // POST: api/Game
    [HttpPost, Route("initiation")]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Initiate> PurchaseInitiationAsync([FromBody]Initiate value)
    {

        if (value == null)
        {
            var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Request is NULL! Please check your data.")),  
                ReasonPhrase = "Request is NULL! Please check your data."
            };

            throw new HttpResponseException(message);
        }

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value),
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json"
        );



        HttpResponseMessage response =
            await httpClient.PostAsync("http://test:1907/purchase_initiation", content);


        var obj = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Initiate>(
            new List<MediaTypeFormatter>
            {
                new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()
            }).Result;

        return obj;
    }


}
```

Comment: Not that it matters for this question, however if you paste an exception in your question, its often good practice to show the line you get it on.

Comment: I think registering JSONMediaTypeFormatter in WebApiCongif will solve this issue. `config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());`

Comment: nope didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I can only reproduce this if the request content type hitting `api/v1/pin/initiation` is `text/html`. You say that your Postman settings are set to `application/json` and body is `x-www-form-urlencoded`, but from my testing if that was the case the exception you've shown above wouldn't be thrown.

I would double check that Postman is actually sending the correct content type header by opening the Postman console (CTRL+ALT+C) and inspecting the request headers.

[image]

Comment: here is the postman console `Request Headers:
Content-Type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
cache-control:"no-cache"
Postman-Token:"bbaa8370-bf3c-42a4-b10b-aff07b862885"
User-Agent:"PostmanRuntime/7.6.0"
Host:"localhost:61217"
accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate"
content-length:192`

Comment: `Response Headers:
Cache-Control:"no-cache"
Pragma:"no-cache"
Content-Type:"application/json; charset=utf-8"
Expires:"-1"
Server:"Microsoft-IIS/10.0"
X-AspNet-Version:"4.0.30319"
X-SourceFiles:"=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcMTk3MTk5XERvY3VtZW50c1xWaXN1YWwgU3R1ZGlvIDIwMTdcUHJvamVjdHNcRVBJTk1pZGRsZVdhcmVBUElcRVBJTk1pZGRsZVdhcmVBUElcYXBpXHYxXHBpblxpbml0aWF0aW9u?="
X-Powered-By:"ASP.NET"
Date:"Wed, 06 Feb 2019 17:38:22 GMT"
Content-Length:"2583`

Comment: Ok, so is this exception is being thrown when you request `/api/v1/pin/initiation`? Can you try ruling out the code in the action by returning a hard coded `Initiate`. If this works, it could be that exception is being thrown by whatever you're calling at `http://test:1907/purchase_initiation` and that exception is bubbling up to the response you're seeing in Postman.

Comment: I think it is due to this code segment `HttpContent content = new StringContent(
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value),
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json"
            );` I can see correct JSON data is in value. Is there a way to check content?

Comment: So you're saying that line of code is throwing the `UnsupportedMediaTypeException` in the original question? Have you attached a debugger and confirmed that is the case? Did you do what I suggested in the previous comment and check what happens if you return a hard coded object?

Comment: yes I did and you are right. There is an error in the service. When debugging, it writes content byte[238]. I can't see my data. However there is data that I send in value. How can I check if there is correct data in content?

Comment: I doubt this is where the problem is, but you can read it back out with `content.ReadAsStringAsync()`. Have you tried re-creating the `POST` to `http://test:1907/purchase_initiation` with Postman to see what that returns?

Comment: I found out why this error occurs. The body x-www-form-urlencodedparameters starts with lower case (referenceId, productCode...etc) But some how my code makes them all uppercase. How could this happen? `{"ReferenceId":"28944118272","ProductCode":"001002461285","Quantity":"1","InitiationResultCode":null,"ValidatedToken":null,"Version":"V1","Signature":"73b36a52ad3b0c85dc6b1a8a536e75bf","ApplicationCode":"52e7cf966b724749a7c4efadc3727ed7"}`

Comment: damn model :):)